# Is there an emacs mode (or other editor) for editing binary records?

Tags: emacs, binary-data, mode

I'm looking for a way to view and edit files of fixed-length binary records with fields consisting of various raw data types like integer, string, etc.

There is no way to directly infer the format, but one could have a simple printf-like format descriptor like: `"%12d: (%d, %f)\n"` to parse and print out every single record.

One could also imagine more complicated dynamic records, for example, where one field indicates the length of the next.  This could be combined with compression or other modes. The format could also be extended.

Has anyone seen anything with similar functionality? The closest mode I could find on the web is `rec-mode` for text-based records.  I wrote a small ROOT TTree-based extension to print out such files, but it would be nice to edit them directly in emacs.

Comment: Have you tried `hexl-mode`?

Comment: `hexl-mode` is certainly the generic way to edit binary files.  Are you looking for something which would parse the file based on a pre-specified format, and present individual fields for editing?

Comment: I thought of [forms-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/forms/index.html), which is meant for editing text records with variable field lengths, but has some variables that could be (ab)used to deal with binary data...

Comment: I currently use hexl-mode, but I have to parse the fields, including their integer and floating point values, by hand.  Perhaps forms-mode could be coerced to format binary data, but it looks like the whole premise is ASCII fields (and record separator strings like <tab>.   I was looking for something simple that you could just give a short format string to parse individual records.  Perhaps with an output filter like GUD-mode?